# Bootstrap tooltips conflicts with scrolling

Tags: bootstrap-4, vuejs2, tooltip

Can you please tell me if there is a way around this problem? to make the tooltip ignore the scrollbar

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    show: false
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.11/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.12.0/dist/bootstrap-vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.5.0/dist/bootstrap-vue-icons.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.4.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.12.0/dist/bootstrap-vue.css"/>
<div id="app">
  <div class="container" style="max-width: 1024px;">
    <div class="row" style="text-align: center">
      <div style="background-color: yellow; width: 55%; overflow-y: scroll">
        <div @click="show = !show" id="tooltip-button-1">
          Click Me
        </div>
        <b-tooltip target="tooltip-button-1" triggers="click" placement="right">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</b-tooltip>
      </div>
      <div style="background-color: red; width: 45%;">
           <div style="height: 40px"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
 <style>
    .tooltip-inner {
        max-width: 200px!important
    }
    </style>
```

Can you please tell me if there is a way around this problem? to make the tooltip ignore the scrollbar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by moving the scroll block out of the block with which there was a problem

apparently the scroll in the browser has its own special attributes that do not allow you to go beyond it